# Update MySql values with it's current value in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a column called name in a table info

So I want to update that with it's current value, like this name + user_input. I tried with this code but not working

```
mysql_query("UPDATE info SET name = name + '$user_input' WHERE id='$user_id'");
```

But It returns 0 and update column to 0....

Any idea how to accomplish this task??

Comment: What do you expect the `+` to do? How do you add two strings?

Comment: Why is this tagged for both Oracle and MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CONCAT` to concatenate string in MySQL (`+` is for addition arithmetic operations which I guess can't properly work with *names*) :

```
UPDATE info SET name = CONCAT(name,'$user_input') WHERE id='$user_id'
```